# Do I need to call both .dispose() (javax.jcr.Binary) and .close() (java.io.InputStream)?

Tags: java, aem, sling

Do I need to define the Binary object separately so I can call `.dispose();` on it (see `methodOne()`) or will that be handled automatically when auto-closing the InputStream (see `methodTwo()`)?

```
private void methodOne(Resource resource) {
    Binary binary = resource.getValueMap().get("jcr:data", Binary.class);
    try {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = binary.getStream();
            // ...do something with the InputStream...
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            LOG.error("RepositoryException trying to get an InputStream from the resource.");
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        binary.dispose();
    }
}

private void methodTwo(Resource resource) {
    try (InputStream is = resource.getValueMap().get("jcr:data", Binary.class).getStream()) {
        // ...do something with the InputStream...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("IOException from trying to auto-close InputStream.");
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        LOG.error("RepositoryException trying to get an InputStream from the resource.");
    }
}
```

I'm genuinely confused on how to even test if the anonymous Binary resource in methodTwo is being disposed of properly, which is why I'm even asking this question in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the class you're getting the stream from documents that closing the stream is sufficient, then you need to ensure that you list the other closeable resources in the `try` to get `try-with-resources` to close them for you.

You've said `Binary` doesn't implement `AutoCloseable`. Irritating. :-) You could always define a wrapper (as I assume this isn't the only place you need to deal with this), something along these lines:

```
public class ACBinaryWrapper implements AutoCloseable {
    private Binary binary;

    public ACBinaryWrapper(Binary binary) {
        this.binary = binary;
    }

    public Binary getBinary() {
        return this.binary;
    }

    public void close() { 
        if (this.binary != null) {
            Binary b = this.binary;
            this.binary = null;
            b.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
private void yourMethod(Resource resource) {
    try (
        ACBinaryWrapper acbinary = new ACBinaryWrapper(
            resource.getValueMap().get("jcr:data", Binary.class)
        );
        InputStream is = acbinary.getBinary().getStream();
    ) {
        // ...do something with the InputStream...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ...appropriate handling...
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        // ...appropriate handling...
    }
}
```

Note how `binary` is listed separately from `is`.

---

Your `LOG` statements in the `IOException` handler and such seemed to assume that the only I/O error that could occur was when closing the stream. In general, reading from streams can cause an I/O error as well.

Comment: Much appreciated for the clarification on IOException handling as well as the quick answer! javax.jcr.Binary doesn't extend Closeable or AutoCloseable so declaring it within the try-with-resources declaration wouldn't necessarily handle the call to `.dispose();` though, right?

Comment: @gdubz: Sorry, my mistake, I assumed it was `AutoCloseable`. One second...

Comment: That's quite alright. Reading the comments in the class, it sounds like I'm responsible for calling both `.close()` on the InputStream and `.dispose()` on the Binary object itself. I'm just not clear the implications of calling `.getStream()` off a chained initialization (I guess leaving an anonymous Binary object out there?), or how to even test/debug this.

Comment: @gdubz: If you're responsible for calling `dispose`, then yeah, you can't just get the stream from a chained initialization. I've updated the answer above.

Comment: Your wrapper solution is very elegant. I'll give that a try. Thank you so much for your help with this!